# XMLSerializer option fields

Tags: serialization, f#

The following f# script does not serialize the option field:

```
open System.Xml.Serialization

[<CLIMutable>]
type Repo = { 
        [<XmlElement("mandatory")>] mandatory : string
        [<XmlElement("optional", IsNullable=true)>] optional : string option 
    }
    with
    static member serialize data (filename: string) =  
        let writer = System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(data.GetType())
        use file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filename)
        writer.Serialize(file, data)

let x = { mandatory = "insert text"; optional = Some("optional text") }

Repo.serialize x @"d:\tmp\prova.xml"
```

The result xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Repo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<mandatory>insert text</mandatory>
<optional />
</Repo>
```

Why the "optional" element is empty?

Comment: Most probably the XmlSerializer doesn't know about the option type or records. You already specified IsNullable. So either just use null or string or try a different XMLSerializer.

Comment: so the answer is I cannot use XMLSerializer to serialize option fields, right?

Comment: That would be my guess but I might be wrong hence the comment. If you need the option type I would explore the XML type provider, FSpickler or DataContractSerializer.

Comment: For example FSPickler gave me the following output: `optional><Some>text1</Some></optional></value>`